# textarea is Filled with White Spaces

Tags: html, shopify

First off, I'm using Shopify.  I have a `textarea` and it is filled with white spaces when the page loads.  I know why, it's because of the HTML, but I don't know why the browser is served different HTML than the HTML I created.

Here is my code:

```
<textarea name="contact[body]" id="ContactFormMessage" placeholder="Your message...."></textarea>
```

And this is what is served to the browser:

```
<textarea rows="10"
    name="contact[body]"
    id="ContactFormMessage"
    placeholder="Your message">

</textarea>
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

you have empty space between beginning textarea tag and closing tag. you need to remove that.

```html
<textarea rows="10"
    name="contact[body]"
    id="ContactFormMessage"
    placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks but that isn't what I made. My code doesn't have that space, but when it gets to the browser it's formatted differently

Comment: I might be able to give you a better solution if you share your website's address ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have no value in your textarea block.  If you wanted the textarea to be initialized with "foo", you would do

```
<textarea name="contact[body]" id="ContactFormMessage" placeholder="Your message">foo</textarea>
```

As an aside, the square brace is not a valid character for the name attribute.  (See https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#h-6.2)